# ES6 undefined ${this.name}

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Amigos estoy intentando lo siguiente

```
class Player{

    //todo lo que resiba este const será la clase persona
    constructor(nombre,edad){
        nombre == this.nombre;
        edad == this.edad;

    }

    mA(){
        console.log(`la edad es de ${this.edad}`)
    }
}


let px = new Player('kyo',21);
px.mA();
```

pero me da

> la edad es de undefined

Alguien sabe porqué? estoy saltandome algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes los siguientes errores.

1. El el contructor se inicializan las propiedades por lo que el operador es `=` que es igual a y tu estas equivocado al usar `==` que es comparar si el valor de la izquierda es igual al valor de la derecha
2. El contructor recibe las propiedades y las inicializa así `this.prop = prop`

Entonces el código final es:

```js
    class Player{
    
        //todo lo que resiba este const será la clase persona
        constructor(nombre,edad){
            this.nombre = nombre
            this.edad = edad
    
        }
    
        mA(){
            console.log(`la edad es de ${this.edad}`)
        }
    }
    
    
    let px = new Player('kyo',21);
    px.mA();
```

El resultado final que obtendrás es:

```
"la edad es de 21"
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**

1. Usar `=` es para asignar un valor, es decir `a = 9;`
2. Usar `==` es para indicar si el lado izquierdo es igual en valor al lado derecho, por ejemplo `10 == 10`
3. Usar `===` es para indicar si el lado izquierdo es igual en tipo y valor al lado derecho; por ejemplo `10 === 10` que dará `true` y `10 === "10"` dará false por que el valor de la derecha es una cadena de texto

Comment: Gracias te amo Shadow, sigo viendo lo mi bd si se de algo te posteo, te tengo para mejor respuesta eres increíble.